# How to align client and IdentityServer cookies

Tags: cookies, identityserver4

I'm moving an ASP.NET web application away from Forms authentication to OIDC authentication through IdentityServer, with implicit flow for getting an ID token. Forms authentication has options in the client web.config such as 'timeout' and 'slidingExpiration' and I'm looking for a way to make sure the client is just as configurable when using IdentityServer.

I understand there are two separate cookie management systems in this scenario - the client's and IdentityServer's. I would like to align them as much as possible and have a single place for configuring these options. This could be either at either end, one handing responsibility to the other.

One option I've explored is setting UseTokenLifetime = true on both ends and then using the IdentityServer Client property IdentityTokenLifetime as a way to configure timeout for the client. Both cookies should then expire at the same time specified by the IdentityTokenLifetime. When the client's cookie times out it'll redirect to IdentityServer for authentication, where the login prompt will be shown because its own cookie will have expired too. However, I don't think this allows a sliding expiration option?

Another option might be to set UseTokenLifetime back to false, configure cookie options in the client cookie middleware, and ensure the client sends prompt=login when authenticating. This means even if IdentityServer has cookie settings which don't match the client (e.g. the IdentityServer cookie is still valid after client's has expired), it'll still always show the login prompt. The downside to this seems to be that it would inhibit SSO should I add more clients, because they'll always have to login for each client.

I would appreciate any thoughts on this

Thanks